# Tasker (switch off mobile data automatically) causing trouble under CyanogenMod

Tags: cyanogenmod, tasker, automation, mobile-network, mobile-data

I used to use this Tasker profile for nearly a year now already and it used to work fine, until I recently switched from the Samsung default UI TouchWiz to CyanogenMod on my Galaxy Note.

The Task triggered by the profile (which I'll post further below) looks like the following:

```
<TaskerData sr="" dvi="1" tv="4.2u3m">
    <Task sr="task15">
        <cdate>1390655578675</cdate>
        <edate>1391243001675</edate>
        <id>15</id>
        <nme>mobile data [off]</nme>
        <Action sr="act0" ve="3">
            <code>30</code>
            <Int sr="arg0" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg1" val="11"/>
            <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg3" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg4" val="0"/>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act1" ve="3">
            <code>37</code>
            <lhs>%SCREEN</lhs>
            <op>1</op>
            <rhs>off</rhs>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act2" ve="3">
            <code>433</code>
            <Int sr="arg0" val="0"/>
        </Action>
    </Task>
</TaskerData>
```

And this is the profile which triggers the above task:

```
<TaskerData sr="" dvi="1" tv="4.2u3m">
    <Profile sr="prof16" ve="2">
        <cdate>1390655626259</cdate>
        <clp>true</clp>
        <edate>1391189579981</edate>
        <id>16</id>
        <limit>true</limit>
        <mid0>15</mid0>
        <nme>auto mobile data [off]</nme>
        <State sr="con0">
            <code>123</code>
            <Int sr="arg0" val="0"/>
        </State>
        <State sr="con1">
            <code>110</code>
            <Int sr="arg0" val="1"/>
            <Int sr="arg1" val="1"/>
            <Int sr="arg2" val="1"/>
            <Int sr="arg3" val="1"/>
        </State>
    </Profile>
    <Task sr="task15">
        <cdate>1390655578675</cdate>
        <edate>1391170165892</edate>
        <id>15</id>
        <nme>mobile data [off]</nme>
        <Action sr="act0" ve="3">
            <code>30</code>
            <Int sr="arg0" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg1" val="11"/>
            <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg3" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg4" val="0"/>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act1" ve="3">
            <code>37</code>
            <lhs>%SCREEN</lhs>
            <op>1</op>
            <rhs>off</rhs>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act2" ve="3">
            <code>433</code>
            <Int sr="arg0" val="0"/>
        </Action>
    </Task>
</TaskerData>
```

What the profile should do is switching the mobile data connection if it's turned on-off 11 seconds after the display turned black. Seems not too tricky.

But running CyanogenMod, it doesn't work anymore; what now happens is: after I booted my smartphone, everything works like a charm (connection via mobile data is stable and accessible immediately after you turn it on). But after the first time you switch off the screen (that's when Tasker kicks in), nothing works anymore. The mobile data is switched off, yes - or at least, there's no connection anymore. But the system itself seems not to realize this properly as both, in the settings as well as in the notification bar, it's still displayed as "on". You can switch it off there too, but either way, there's no way to turn it back on (yes the switches still work, but they don't have any effect).

Description:

```
Profil: mobile data [off] (16)
    Status: Displaystatus [ Ist:Aus ]
    Status: Mobiles Netzwerk [ 2G:An 3G:An 3G - HSPA:An 4G:An ]
Eingang: mobile data [off] (15)
    A1: Warte [ MS:0 Sekunden:11 Minuten:0 Std.:0 Tage:0 ] 
    A2: If [ %SCREEN ~ off ]
    A3: mobile data [ setzen:Aus ]
```

<sup>(Sorry, it came out in German since I use Tasker in German)</sup>

Comment: Which version of Cyanogen are you using? Are you using a stable, testing, or nightly version? Have you reported this problem to the Cyanogen developers?

Comment: I use stable, 10.1.3 which is Android 4.2.2. Haven't reported it to the CM-Team (yet)

Comment: Hmm, the XML descriptions are not as useful as they could be, due to the `<code>` tags. Could you replace them with the contents of Tasker's "Description to clipboard" export, please?

Comment: A few more thoughts: Does Tasker deactivate the profile when the screen turns back on? If you explicitly execute a Tasker task to enable mobile data, does it help? If you connect to WiFi, then disconnect again, does it help?

Comment: @TreborRude sorry, but how's that workin'? Couldn't find nothing about that in the helping-section.

Comment: About what, @user43961? Exporting task / profile descriptions? For that, long-press a task or profile, then tap the '...' button in the action bar. Select `Export`, then `Description to Clipboard`. Then edit your question, and replace the XML with the description that was exported. Or was it something from my other comment that you were asking about?

Comment: oh dear, I thought you referred to a function within this platform (like that there was a special way of posting code) ... I'll add it in a sec

Comment: What about my questions four comments up, @user43961?

Comment: Yes that seems to work in terms of the effect. But let's say mobile data is set to "on". If I now disable it via tasker, the CM-Interface still shows the mobile data to be swiched on... it just doesn't realize that it's already turned off.